# What causes NSolve to re-order variables?

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following code

```
theta = 120
NSolve[-0.034298780658685656 + y == 
   Tan[theta*Pi/180] (-0.012483735231386907 + 
      x) && -0.028199999999999996 + y == 0 && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}]
```

to solve for the intersection of two straight lines. One of the lines have a slope of `theta` (in degrees). Accidentally, I found that `theta = 120` will give the solution `{{y -> 0.0282, x -> 0.0160049}}`, i.e., the variables `x` and `y` are swapped in order though I used `{x,y}` in `NSolve`. However almost all other values of `theta`, 119, 121, … will not cause this to happen. My question is, what causes `NSolve` to think it has to order `y` before `x` in the solution? How can I make sure that the variables in the solution of `NSolve` are strictly in the order as I provided?

Comment: Can you write code so that the order doesn't matter?

Comment: @Michael, yeah, that could be a solution. But just curious to find out what caused this to happen and how to avoid.

Comment: Looks like a buglet.

Answer (score 1):

If the symbolic `Tan[theta*Pi/180]` is replaced by the number `Tan[theta*Pi/180.]`, then the variable order is preserved:

```
theta = 120;
NSolve[
-0.034298780658685656 + y == Tan[theta*Pi/180.] (-0.012483735231386907 + x) &&
 -0.028199999999999996 + y == 0 && x > 0 && y > 0,
 {x, y}]
(*  {{x -> 0.0160049, y -> 0.0282}}  *)
```

I also get the `{x, y}` order if we add `x` to both sides of the second equation:

```
NSolve[
-0.034298780658685656 + y == Tan[theta*Pi/180] (-0.012483735231386907 + x) &&
 -0.028199999999999996 + y + x == 0 + x && x > 0 && y > 0,
 {x, y}]
(*  {{x -> 0.0160049, y -> 0.0282}}  *)
```

Perhaps it is related to the second equation being separable and having a symbolic, numeric, nonnumber coefficient.  I don't know why that would be.  The second equation being free of `x` means it could be solved first.  Maybe that's part of it.